# Removing only-ubiquity / maybe-ubiquity from GRUB boot parameters does not change anything

Tags: grub2, 20.04, ubiquity

I am customizing the Ubuntu 20.04 live ISO. I want it to boot into the live environment, without launching ubiquity in the contained GNOME desktop environment. I did some research, and I am pretty sure the only-ubiquity and the maybe-ubiquity parameters do that. So I removed them. Then, when I boot, Ubiquity launches. Do I need to edit some other file, or is this parameter not useful anymore? If so, how do I make the live ISO launch into the live environment automatically?

Comment: Have a look at the boot system of persistent live systems created by [mkusb-dus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). I think that kind of hands-on experience can help you by showing examples of something similar to what you want.

Comment: Look at the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and the boot options (on the 'linux lines').

Comment: @sudodus I changed the parameters in that file

Comment: In  persistent live systems created by mkusb-dus I manage to change things concerning ubiquity. Please follow the path described in my first comment.

Comment: @iNeedHelp Try making a Persistent USB with **mkusb**. If you boot in the first option, "persistent live", you should see that the "install" option has been skipped. When making a Persistent USB from scratch I only get the "install" option when I use "maybe-ubiquity" or "only-ubiquity" in /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

Comment: Depending on how you make the Live USB, grub.cfg may be in multiple locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after looking around in the system.
You need to remove the only-ubiquity and maybe-ubiquity boot options, and then disable the ubiquity service (`systemctl disable ubiquity.service`). That way, it will boot into the live environment.